# Different values when debugging than in console?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm running an Angular application that is returning two distinct values simultaneously. I'm curious if anyone has seen this:

```
function updateValues() {
    var activeNavButton = pageNavButtons.eq(values.currentPage);
    pageNavButtons.removeClass("active");
    activeNavButton.addClass("active");

    pageNavButtons.each(function () {
        var forceRender = $(this).get(0).offsetLeft;
    });

    var w = 0;
    $(".pages button").each(function () {
        w = w + $(this).outerWidth(true)
    });
    var b=0;

    completeHandler();
}
```

This is straightforward as can be. Switch which item is "active", and then force a render refresh. You'll notice none of this code is really doing anything, but thats okay. I left out some of the less important, unrelated stuff.

Yep, I'm frustrated enough that I'm trying to force the render refresh in multiple ways at once.

In the chrome debugger, if you break on this line:

```
var b = 0
```

the following occurs:

```
w = 790 //Watcher
```

However, if you open the console while the script is still at that break point and literally copy and paste the preceding 4 lines:

```
var w = 0;
$(".pages button").each(function () {
    w = w + $(this).outerWidth(true)
});
```

It returns 800 for the value of w.
An important thing to note: the .active class gives the selected element a "bold" font, thus changing the element width. I'm positive this is related to the problem but I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue really is.

As you can see, I'm accessing offsetWidth to try to force the browser to update the elements but its not working.

Any ideas? This is driving me absolutely insane.

Comment: have you tried using a really short setTimeout()? Is issue occurring in multiple browsers? Could be something to do with browser repainting lag. A demo that replicates this would help

Comment: I did try that, which essentially does the same thing as what I'm doing with the break point. The problem is that a timeout is a hack, and it's inconsistent. The render time seems to depend on system resources and so if I set it to 50ms it might not be enough time, particularly on slower devices. And even then, if I up it to like 100 or 200 you'll get noticeable jitter. I'd rather find the actual source of the problem here.

Comment: Not much way to help if we can't see it

Answer (score 1):

Okay. This may seem dumb but on large code bases it might not be terribly surprising:

Turns out that the button's base CSS class (a ways up in the hierarchy) had a transition: all 150ms on it.

This caused a delay, which caused widths to return incorrectly as you might expect because, and this is the important part, **font weight is included in transition all**.

Because of this, the font weight would change 150ms later, and those extra couple of pixels of width (in certain cases) would register "late". No wonder my timers seemed to arbitrarily succeed: I was guessing.

**Lesson learned: Don't use transition: all unless you have a good reason. Target the things you want to actually transition.**

Hope this helps somebody else! Cheers.